# Powersell Ram usage for exact process

Tags: powershell

Good day,
There are a lot of the same themes, but i wonder how i can get Ram usage for the exact process, for instance, notepad++ (need to search by name). The output shouldn't be in the table view, just MB and %

Thank you for your help

Comment: `Get-Process | ? {$_.Name -eq 'notepad++'} | Select-Object Name,@{Name='RamUsage';Expression={[System.Math]::Round(($_.WorkingSet/1MB), 2)}}`

Comment: Resolved, thank you!